# Increment value of a variable within loop that reads line from file in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a loop that should be executed for each line in a file. Within that loop I need to increment a variable. However, the value is not getting incremented. How can I increment it properly?

### Code excerpt

```
i=1;

for line in `cat sPSEE_disprot/disorder_prediction_threshold_info.txt`
do
    echo $i;
    dir="predicted_disorder/1_$i"
    mkdir $dir

    echo $line;
    ((i=i+1));
done
```

### Output

```
1

-0.5930735 // this is the content of file

1

mkdir: cannot create directory `predicted_disorder/1_1': File exists

-0.593253

1

mkdir: cannot create directory `predicted_disorder/1_1': File exists

-0.593468

1

mkdir: cannot create directory `predicted_disorder/1_1': File exists

-0.593581
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Could you run `head sPSEE_disprot/disorder_prediction_threshold_info.txt | cat -A' to give us a small glimpse of your input data, and update your question to include this? Because I suspect your text is the source of the problem, so to see it, we can check if that might be the case.

Comment: here is the output: "-0.703276$
-0.673786$
-0.7117085$
-0.7430455$
-0.7125195$
-0.6949005$
-0.6982505$
-0.703854$
-0.713628$
-0.717174$
" I am wondering about "$" signs!! From where those came!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you overlooked that `(())` needs to be preceded by a `$` to work:

```
i=1
echo $i
: $((i=i+1))
echo $i
```

Also note that semicolons are useless (null-statements) as the last character in a line.

Comment: Thanks... it worked!!!! Following the suggestion in  (http://askubuntu.com/questions/385528/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-bash) I tried "i=$((i+1))", which did not work. That's made me to ignore "$"... however, thanks !!

Comment: It depends on the shell.  The question isn't tagged Bash so this answer is correct, but in Bash, the script in the question can work — Bash treats `((…))` similar to `$((…))` but doesn't process the output, or thereabouts.  Korn shell also handles `((…))` roughly the same as Bash (or vice versa).  The `$((…))` notation is POSIX-compliant; `((…))` is not.  Dash and Heirloom Shell do not handle `((…))` — it is treated as a double sub-shell AFAICT (no syntax error, but not the desired effect).

Comment: Which shell (and which version of it) are you using? `((i=i+1))` works fine in recent versions of bash and zsh. Don't know about Korn Shell.